# New column from row operations in another column using PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe, for example GDP, I would like to create a new column called GDP growth % from the GDP column using the formula ((New GDP-Old GDP)/New GDP)*100,

```
a = {'GDP': [50,59,63,75,80,99,35]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df
```

Comment: check pct_change ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['GDP_pct_change'] = df['GDP'].pct_change()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
You might want to read the documentation. The 'getting started' section covers this topic.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html#how-to-create-new-columns-derived-from-existing-columns

For your specific question you can try:

```
df = df.assign(growth=df.GDP/df.GDP.loc[0] *100 - 100)
```